# Using gzip to compress rest response

Tags: spring, rest, gzip, spring-boot

I have a rest service which is exposed to end user. This service sends response(say 500K) and the response times are high.

How can we use Gzip to compress the response and send.

I'm using Spring boot and maven.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: java has gzip input /output stream that you can use on the server side

Comment: are you using HTTPS?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan: As of now its Http but in future it will be HTTPS

Comment: Is there any sensitive data in the response body?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan: Yes, we have sensitive data as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring boot allows you to simply configure tomcat to use compression via your application.properties/yaml

`server.tomcat.compression: on`

(for more options see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#how-to-enable-http-response-compression)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Will try this option and check if it works

Comment: Thanks Lukas. Tomcat provides compression option and is by default disabled. When we turn this on, the response is compressed.

Answer (score 6):

The GZIP configuration was updated in Spring Boot release 1.3. Now, the correct handling is to use `server.compression.enabled` property.

```
server.compression.enabled=true
```

See the [Enable HTTP response compression](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.x/reference/htmlsingle/#how-to-enable-http-response-compression) chapter in the reference docs for configuration details such as response size and content type. Please read the [Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.3-Release-Notes#http-response-compression) for the motivations of this change.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your container. Many will do this for you transparently at the server level, you shouldn't have to do anything at all with your code.

Consider this [Tomcat example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/enable-gzip-compression-in-tomcat/).